# how the sql works by < Or > in a sql about using index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

how can this sql use index and how can this sql not use index.

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `d` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_abd` (`a`,`b`,`d`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

explain select * from testtable where a > 1;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | testtable | NULL       | ALL  | idx_abd       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   10 |    80.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+


explain select * from testtable where a < 1;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | testtable | NULL       | range | idx_abd       | idx_abd | 4       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

why the first one can't use index but the second use index.
how the index works inside?

Comment: In `EXPLAIN`:  "Using index" means that the index is 'covering'.  "Using index condition" means that the Engine tested other conditions, rather than the 'handler'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case, MySQL optimizer (based on statistics) decided that it is better to do a Full Table Scan, instead of first doing Index Lookups, and then do a Data Lookup.

In the first query of yours, the condition used (`a > 1`) is effectively needing to access 10 out of 11 rows. Always remember that, MySQL does [Cost based optimization](http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/cost-based-optimization.html) (tries to minimize the cost). The process is basically:

> 1. Assign a cost to each operation.
> 2. Evaluate how many operations each possible plan would take.
> 3. Sum up the total.
> 4. Choose the plan with the lowest overall cost.

Now, default MySQL cost for `io_block_read_cost` is **1**. In the first query, you are going to roughly have two times the I/O block reads (first for index lookups and then Data lookups). So, the cost would come out roughly as **20**, in case MySQL decides to use the index. Instead, if it does the Table Scan directly, the cost would be roughly **11** (Data lookup on all the rows). That is why, it decided to use Table Scan instead of Range based Index Scan.

If you want to get details about the Cost breakup, please run each of this queries by appending `EXPLAIN format=JSON` to them and executing them, like below:

```
EXPLAIN format=JSON select * from testtable where a > 1;
```

You can also see how Optimizer compared various plans before locking into a particular strategy. To do this, execute the queries below:

```
/* Turn tracing on (it's off by default): */
SET optimizer_trace="enabled=on";
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE a > 1; /* your query here */
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OPTIMIZER_TRACE;
/* possibly more queries...
 When done with tracing, disable it: */
SET optimizer_trace="enabled=off";
```

Check more details at MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing.html

Comment: oh，yes,when i use a > 10 in sql it show that i used index. thank you.and i learned a new way in expain sql;

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to read the both the index and the data pages.  On such small data, that can be less efficient (although the difference in performance -- like the duration of each query -- is quite small).

Your table has 10 rows, which presumably are all on a single data page.  MySQL considers it more efficient to just read the 10 rows directly and do the comparison.

The value of indexes is when you have larger tables, particularly tables that span many data pages.  One primary use is to reduce the number of data pages being read.